# Difficulty Integrating Modal Window Code into Div

Tags: jquery, html, css, video

I had the following code created to accommodate a temporary tabled designed site:

```
<a class="popup-modal" href="#videos">
  <img src="images/playvideobuttn.jpg" width="139" height="43" alt="" />
</a>

<div id="videos" class="mfp-hide white-popup-block">
  <video poster="images/play-poster.jpg" data-setup="{}" preload="auto" onclick="this.play();">
    <source src="images/b2bpromo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="images/b2bpromo.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>

  <p><a class="popup-modal-dismiss" href="#">X</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

I had successfully integrated this into the tabled site without issue; however now that I am re-imaging the site using CSS and divs, I am unable to get the code to integrate properly. It's been a while since I've developed a site and I'm a bit unclear on this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!
Steve M.

Comment: "I am unable to get the code to integrate properly" what do you mean? any jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Click me</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Head:-)</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Modal content goes here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Get outta here!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/ut3rp9ae/1/